# CQRS events between multiple services

Tags: java, spring, cqrs, axon

We have a microservice that listens for events, lets call this `AuditService` for now. It listens for Audit Events (`AuditEvent`) on rabbitmq. Any one who wants to call the `AuditService` needs to create and fire a `AuditEvent`. We have shared the `AuditEvent` pojo in a common module so it can be shared.

There is a event listener in the `AuditService` that listens for the `AuditEvent` from the rabbitmq queue. When we get a message we then do some processing/validation on the `AuditEvent` and then save it to the `AuditEntry` database table.

We then want to publish another event. Lets call this `AuditPublishEvent`. So in order to do this we create another command (`AuditPublishCommand`) which in turn fires the`AuditPublishEvent`. This event is again for the queue and any service that publishes the `AuditEvent` will listen for it. There will be a service to send it as an email, and another to send it as a push, etc.

At the moment what we are doing on the AuditService is

```
Listen for AuditEvent
  |
  v
Trigger AuditEvent event handler
  |
  v
Validate audit event and process it
  |
  v
Save it to the database
  |
  v
If save is successful then send AuditPublishEvent to queue via AuditPublishCommand
```

Note that the last part needs to be synchronous, meaning if the db save failed we don't want to send an email or such. This is currently done by calling the commandGateway from within the event handler in the `AuditService`, is it correct to call the commandGateway from the `EventListener`, if not what is the alternative?

The question is, is this the correct way/best practice of doing things using the Axon framework and spring?

Comment: do  you have write and read services? if you have separate read service then you can send SendEmailCommand to so the email service inside the read service event handler after saving the data.

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is the best way to address the problem is hard to say, as it would require much more information about your domain. 
What I can say, is that what your doing is technically allright. You mentioned you are unsure if the event published after the `AuditEvent` is stored is only published when the database changes are committed. That depends on how the event is published. If you use the EventBus to publish it and use the SpringAMQPPublisher, you’re safe. 
If you publish it directly, this may not be the case.

Axon uses a unitOfWork to coordinate activities in different phases if processing. Handlers are called in the ‘started’ phase. A database commit is done in the phase after: ‘commit’. 
If you want to be sure the message to AMQP after the commit, register a handler to the afterCommit phase. Handlers for this phase are not invoked on a rollback. 
You can add the UnitOfWork as a parameter to you @EventHandler annoted method. Axon will automatically inject it for you.